# CodeIgniter 3: form is not submitting

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, submit

I'm new to codeigniter, I have tried everything but my form is still not submitting to the database.

here's my code. I seriously can't find where I went wrong anymore.

**VIEW**

```
<?= form_open('forms/submit_shifter_form');?>              
<div id="form-interview-fill-mainform" class="form-group">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>Reason/s for shifting:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-input" name="shifter_reason">
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label>Strengths:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-input" name="shifter_strength">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label>Weaknesses:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-input" name="shifter_weakness">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div> 
<?php echo form_submit('submit','Confirm', 'class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="submit"');?>   
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed ');

class Forms extends CI_Controller {
    public function session(){
     if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
        $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
        $data['password'] = $session_data['password'];
        return $data;
    }
}
    public function submit_shifter_form(){
         $shifter = array(
            'course' => $this->input->post('shifter_course'),
            'reason' => $this->input->post('shifter_reason'),
            'strength' => $this->input->post('shifter_strength'),
            'weakness' => $this->input->post('shifter_weakness'),
            'futureContribution' => $this->input->post('shifter_contribution')
        );
       $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $id = $session_data['id'];
        $this->load->model('forms_model');
        $this->forms_model->shifter_form_submit($id,$shifter);
        redirect(site_url('profile'), 'refresh');
    }

}
```

MODEL

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed ');

class Forms_Model extends CI_Model{
    function shifter_form_submit($id,$shifter)
    {
         $this->db->insert('tbl_prototype_shifter',$shifter);
            $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
            $shift = array(
            'studentId' => $id
            );
            $this->db->where('id', $insert_id);
            $this->db->update('tbl_prototype_shifter', $shift);
    }

}
```

My other forms submit data properly in my database, after I added this new form, I seemed like it's not submitting properly anymore. Please, can someone help, I cannot figure out where I went wrong

Comment: where is your submit button?

Comment: I just edited it , sorry

Comment: Are you sure `<?=` prints the form tag?

Comment: I changed it to <?php echo ,still not submitting

Comment: The form is not submitting, can you please also share the error that you are seeing after the form submission?

Comment: and also share the view file name and controller where you are loading this view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You got**

```
$shifter = array(
            'course' => $this->input->post('shifter_course'),
            'reason' => $this->input->post('shifter_reason'),
            'strength' => $this->input->post('shifter_strength'),
            'weakness' => $this->input->post('shifter_weakness'),
            'futureContribution' => $this->input->post('shifter_contribution')
        );
```

But your form has,

```
shifter_reason
shifter_strength
shifter_weakness
```

So rest all fields will be null, is your table accepting null for those remaining fields ?

If no then set some default value,

**In controller**

Make sure you loaded database:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('forms_model');
    $this->load->helper('form');
}
```

and in your other method,

```
$session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
$this->forms_model->shifter_form_submit($session_data['id'],$shifter);
```

In model,

```
function shifter_form_submit($id,$shifter)
{
        // try to insert
        $this->db->insert('tbl_prototype_shifter',$shifter);

        // check if insert was ok
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
        {
              // if ok get last insert id
              $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

              // data to be updated
              $shift = array(
                       'studentId' => $id
              );

              // update 
              $this->db->where('id', $insert_id);
              $this->db->update('tbl_prototype_shifter', $shift);
        }else{
                // failed to insert, so cannot update other table too
               echo $this->db->_error_message();
               throw new Exception("Can't insert the resource");
       }

}
```

Comment: i have added an alert in else, still nothing. i have checked the file names in case of typo, and still not submitting

Comment: im not getting any error message, everytime i click the submit button, the page just reloads itself

Comment: @domin0101 comment this line, and see if there is any error `redirect(site_url('profile'), 'refresh');`

Comment: i commented the line, still the same. i know that when i click the submit button, the function in the controller should show in the url, however in mine, the function doesn't show ,the page just simply reloads

Comment: please debug like this inside model function, `print_r(func_get_args()); die();`, as soon as you submit, and call model method, program should print arguments and quit;

Answer (score 0):

Try this insted of your submitting button.

```
<?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Submit')); ?>
```